# Windows 10 for Enterprise LTSB to CB?

Tags: windows-10

Once Windows 10 for Enterprise **LTSB** installed on a PC, how to change to Windows 10 for Enterprise **CB**?

I mess up during the install, there is more than just one Enterprise version of windows. LTSB do not have the new features (Edge, App store, etc.) the other windows version have. How to change that?

Comment: You should be able to do this the way way you switch branches in the Insider Preview, through Windows Update, have you tried that?

Comment: Like mentioned can achieve via windows update i think try with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to switch from an Enterprise SKU to another is to reinstall. You should be able to upgrade in order to retain settings, but there isn't a simple way to simply add those features.

There is an upgrade path available for lower versions of Windows to higher versions (from home to pro for instance) but these options aren't available for Enterprise.